# SELinux blocks nrpe access to MariaDB

Tags: selinux, mariadb, nrpe, icinga2

I have a few virtual machines in the same LAN monitored by Icinga2 via NRPE.

**[Machine A]**

- CentOS 6
- Icinga2.

**[Machine B]**

- CentOS 6
- MariaDB v10.1.12 properly running

Datadir and socket settings in my.cnf:

```
datadir=/database/mariadb
socket=/database/mariadb/mysql.sock
```

There is also the following symlink:

```
/var/lib/mysql -> /database/mariadb
```

The owner:group of the all above is mysql:mysql.

- SELinux enabled
- /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql v2.0.3

with the following security context:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:nagios_services_plugin_exec_t:s0 /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql
```

- nrpe.cfg contains the following line:

`command[check_mysql]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql -H localhost -u xxx -p xxx -P 3306`

**Now the problem:**

Icinga (from machine A) reports:

```
"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)"
```

If I manually run the folowing line on machine B :

```
sudo -u nrpe /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql -H localhost -u xxx -p xxx -P 3306
```

The result is ok (exit code 0):

```
Uptime: 2085  Threads: 1  Questions: 68204  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 37  Flush...
```

Only when I disable SELinux on machine B (`echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`) Icinga is able to connect to mysql and show the status OK.
But I don't want to disable SELinux. I try to find the proper settings to have both SELinux enabled and Icinga properly connecting to mysql.

[edit]

Everytime when Icinga checks mysql on machine B I see the following two new lines in the audit.log on machine B:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1460038526.265:69): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=4858 comm="check_mysql" name="mysql" dev=dm-0 ino=130900 scontext=system_u:system_r:nagios_services_plugin_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1460038526.265:69): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=3 a1=7fffe4d270f0 a2=6e a3=7fffe4d263e0 items=0 ppid=4857 pid=4858 auid=4294967295 uid=497 gid=498 euid=497 suid=497 fsuid=497 egid=498 sgid=498 fsgid=498 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="check_mysql" exe="/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql" subj=system_u:system_r:nagios_services_plugin_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
setsebool -P nagios_run_sudo 1
```

On host with NRPE. This option is disabled by default in SELinux policy.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it finally. I share the solution below as it might be useful to others too.

I created a working file named audit.log containing just the lines below:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1460038526.265:69): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=4858 comm="check_mysql" name="mysql" dev=dm-0 ino=130900 scontext=system_u:system_r:nagios_services_plugin_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1460038526.265:69): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=3 a1=7fffe4d270f0 a2=6e a3=7fffe4d263e0 items=0 ppid=4857 pid=4858 auid=4294967295 uid=497 gid=498 euid=497 suid=497 fsuid=497 egid=498 sgid=498 fsgid=498 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="check_mysql" exe="/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql" subj=system_u:system_r:nagios_services_plugin_t:s0 key=(null)
```

I ran:

```
sealert -a audit.log > sealert.log
```

The resulted sealert.log contained the explanation of the issue:

> SELinux is preventing /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql from read
>   access on the lnk_file mysql.

and also suggestions for fixing it. As suggested there, I ran the following:

```
grep check_mysql audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
```

This outputted two files: mypol.pp and mypol.te

Finally I ran the following, which completely solved the issue:

```
semodule -i mypol.pp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the socket usually resides inside `/var/lib/mysql` with the data files.

Since you are using a different database dir, SELinux is blocking the request, regardless of the symlink.

You can try to access MySQL via the TCP connection (use `127.0.0.1` and **not** `localhost`)

But this might still cause problems with SELinux with the MySQL daemon itself.

Comment: Already tried to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. But there was no change.